# After uninstalling Ubuntu cannot boot into Windows because of Grub

Tags: grub2, windows

I have Toshiba pc that came with Windows 8, later updated to Windows 8.1
Had Ubuntu 14.04 installed on it fully replacing Windows. Now I want to give my pc to my brother and he wants Windows back. I uninstalled Ubuntu and now can use only live Ubuntu disc. If I do not use it it symphysis goes into black screen and
Gnu Grub version 2.02 beta2-9ubuntu1.3 
Grub>
I don't have a recovery disc. I tried:
- win 10 iso and win7 iso from boot menu
Doesn't load.
Help

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a Windows DVD with those .iso files you have. On Startup of your PC you should be able to get to the *boot menu* where you can select the DVD drive to load and install Windows again.

Comment: ODD means optical disc drive, so that's what you want with a Windows DVD.

Comment: Dvd doesn't load from the boot menu. Black screen shows up. When I type grub> Boot it responds you need to load the kernel first. What to do and how to do it?

Comment: You have to start the DVD at BIOS, well before the GRUB....

Comment: Yes thanks. I did that. As I mentioned in the comments above I could get into boot menu, select USB or CD and it wasn't booting from either one. It's ok now, a technician fixed it. I still don't know what was wrong but it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you extract iso files?

If yes, I think doesn't load because they are not set as bootable files. If you can, make a bootable usb stick on a windows PC and then connect it to your computer and select in boot menu USB. You can use Rufus for example. See [this link](https://rufus.akeo.ie/?locale=en_US) for tutorial.
Or if you can use only ubuntu live cd, try [this](https://www.plop.at/en/winusbinstall.html) to make a bootable usb on it.

If not, extract to the CD, it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did all of the above and could not boot it no matter what. So I gave up (hate to admit) and took it to a technician who fixed it.

Comment: I'm sorry for that you gave it up, but the important is that the computer is fixed :)